# Two S3 Buckets are creating when Deploying using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

am trying to create S3 bucket using serverless framework. but when I deploy, it's creating two buckets one with the name I have mentioned in the `severless.yml` file and another bucket.

serverless.yml

```
service: aws-file-upload-tos3

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

custom:
  fileUploadBucketName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-bucket

resources:
  Resources:
    FileBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.fileUploadBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
```

Buckets created are

[image]

why its creating two buckets like this

Answer (score 2):

By default, serverless framework creates a bucket with a generated name like `<service name>-serverlessdeploymentbuck-1x6jug5lzfnl7` to store your service's stack state.

Each successive version of your serverless app is bundled and uploaded by sls to the deployment bucket, and deployed from there.

I think you have some control over how sls does this if you use the [serverless-deployment-bucket](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-deployment-bucket) plugin.

Comment: am tying to upload xlxs or csv files to S3 using preSignedURL. but access denied when uploading files to the signedURL reason may be the CORS so if I want to set the CORS and Bucket Policy do I need to set it to both the buckets

Comment: I think you're saying that your app running in a browser uploads files to one of your S3 buckets, presumably not the auto-generated deployment bucket. Set the CORS configuration on the bucket your app uploads files to (I would assume that's the FileBucket).

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Serverless Framework creates a number of things on your machine in order to deploy what you have configured in your serverles.yml. It then needs to make use of a service inside AWS called CloudFormation to actually create the resources you configured, like your S3 bucket. The best way to do this is to take the things it created on your machine and upload them to AWS to ensure that the deployment continues without interruption or issue and the best place to do that is S3.

So the Serverless Framework will always (by default) create its own S3 bucket entirely unrelated to what you configured as a location to store the files it generated on your AWS account, then point CloudFormation at it to build the things you configured to get built.

While you have some control over this deployment bucket there always needs to be one. And it is completely unrelated to the bucket you configured.